# Filtering data frame based on values in second data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have 2 data frames:

```
at1 = data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Sample1 = rnorm(5, 50000, 2500),
      Sample2 = rnorm(5, 50000, 2500), Sample3 = rnorm(5, 50000, 2500),
      row.names = "ID")

  Sample1  Sample2  Sample3
A 52626.55 51924.51 50919.90
B 51430.51 49100.38 51005.92
C 50038.27 52254.73 50014.78
D 48644.46 53926.53 51590.05
E 46462.01 45097.48 50963.39

bt1 = data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Sample1 = c(0,1,1,1,1),
      Sample2 = c(0,0,0,1,0), Sample3 = c(1,0,1,1,0), 
      row.names = "ID")

   Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
A       0       0       1
B       1       0       0
C       1       0       1
D       1       1       1
E       1       0       0
```

I would like to filter every cell in at1 based on the value in the corresponding cell in bt1 (0 or 1) and have the result stored in a new data frame ct1. For instance, if bt1[1, "Sample1"] = 1 then ct1[1, "Sample1"] = at1[1, "Sample1"].  If bt1[1, "Sample1"] = 0 then ct1[1, "Sample1"] = 0. My original data frames have more than 100 columns and more than 30,000 rows.

I was wondering if there is an easier way than writing if-loops (e.g. using "apply"?).

Answer (score 7):

Here is a `data.table` solution, and a second simplistic solution

note that I have made `ID` a specific column in the `data.frame` not the `row.names`
for ideological and pratical reasons

- a `data.table` does not have rownames
- I think it is easier to consider them as part of the data

---

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

bt1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Sample1 = c(0,1,1,1,1),
   Sample2 = c(0,0,0,1,0), Sample3 = c(1,0,1,1,0))

at1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Sample1 = rnorm(5, 50000, 2500),
  Sample2 = rnorm(5, 50000, 2500), Sample3 = rnorm(5, 50000, 2500))

# place in long form
at_long <- data.table(melt(at1, id.var = 1))
bt_long <- data.table(melt(bt1, value.name = 'bt_value', id.var = 1))
# set keys for easy merging with data.tabl
setkeyv(at_long, c('ID','variable'))
setkeyv(bt_long, c('ID','variable'))
# merge
combined <- at_long[bt_long]
# set those where 'bt_value == 0' as 0
set(combined, which(combined[['bt_value']]==0), 'value',0)
# or (using the fact that the `bt` data is only 0 or 1
combined[value := value * bt_value]
# then reshape to wide format
dcast(combined, ID~variable, value.var = 'value')
##   ID  Sample1  Sample2  Sample3
## 1  A     0.00     0.00 50115.24
## 2  B 50173.16     0.00     0.00
## 3  C 48216.31     0.00 51952.30
## 4  D 52387.53 50889.95 44043.66
## 5  E 50982.56     0.00     0.00
```

## A second, simplistic approach

If you know that the row  orders are the same in `bt1` and `at1` (your data sets), you can simply multiply the appropriate components of the data.frames  (`*` works element-wise)

```
sample_cols <- paste0('Sample',1:3)
at1[,sample_cols] * bt1[,sample_cols]

##    Sample1  Sample2  Sample3
## 1     0.00     0.00 50115.24
## 2 50173.16     0.00     0.00
## 3 48216.31     0.00 51952.30
## 4 52387.53 50889.95 44043.66
## 5 50982.56     0.00     0.00
```

which you could `cbind` to the `ID` from `at1` or `bt1` or if kept the `ID` as `row.names`, then the row.names would persist.

Comment: Thanks!  I am sure I will use your first solution at some point.  But your simplistic approach, i.e. multiplying the two data frames, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

You can use vectorisation (amongst other things).

For example:

```
ct1 <- at1                           # set ct1 equal to at1
ct1$Sample1[bt1$Sample1 == 0] <- 0   # if bt1$Sample1 = 0, set the value to 0
```

For the second line: `bt1$Sample1 == 0` is a logical vector that is `TRUE` if `bt1$Sample1` is 0, and then we use it as an index into `ct1` in order to set those values to 0. Since `ct1` is initialised to `at1`, all the other rows (where `bt1$Sample1 == 1`) are set to the value in `at1`.

Another way to do this could be using `ifelse`, which is a vectorised form of an if statement:

```
ct1$Sample1 <- ifelse(bt1$Sample1 == 0, 0, at1$Sample1)
```

It means "for each row in `bt1$Sample1`, if `bt1$Sample1[row] == 0` substitute a 0, and otherwise substitute `at1$Sample1[row]`.

You can repeat this for each column you are interested in.

You could loop through columns, *or* you could use something like `vapply` to say:

```
for each column `col` in bt1:
    ct1$col <- ifelse(bt1$col == 0, 0, at1$col)
```

This can be achieved by:

```
ct1 <- vapply(colnames(bt1), function (col) {
           ifelse(bt1[[col]] == 0, 0, at1[[col]])
        }, FUN.VALUE=at1$Sample1)
```

See `?vapply`, but in brief:

- the `colnames(bt1)` means "for each column in `bt`",
- the `function (col) { ifelse(bt1[[col]] == 0, 0, at1[[col]]) }` is the statement in the pseudocode above: set the value eqqual to 0 if bt1 is 0 and set it to the value in `at1` otherwise,
- the `FUN.VALUE=at1$Sample1` is because `vapply` requires an example of what the function will output (in our case, a column of a data frame).

Answer (score 5):

A cheeky approach using `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)
variables <- "bt1.Sample1*at1.Sample1 Sample1,
    bt1.Sample2*at1.Sample2 Sample2,
    bt1.Sample3*at1.Sample3 Sample3"

fn$sqldf("SELECT $variables from at1,bt1 WHERE at1.ROWID=bt1.ROWID")


#   Sample1  Sample2  Sample3
#1     0.00     0.00 55778.34
#2 48819.24     0.00     0.00
#3 51896.14     0.00 52522.69
#4 47946.93 48604.23 47755.30
#5 49423.68     0.00     0.00
```